# How to force host key when provisioning with Vagrant?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, vagrant

Whenever I reprovision from scratch (`vagrant destroy` / `vagrant up`) my machine, the [host key](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/host-key) changes and my ssh clients complain.

I know the host key should be unique, but I am testing at the moment. I would like to control its value. Is it possible to configure this via the `Vagrantfile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is possible. You could make a tar from `/etc/ssh` and distribute & untar that on your new host. For example, in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.define :precise1 do |t|
    t.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
    t.vm.box_url = "file:////links/virt_comp/vagrant/boxes/precise64"
    t.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |prov|
        prov.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nic2", "hostonly", "--hostonlyadapter2", "vboxnet1" ]
    end
    t.vm.provision "shell", path: "./setup.precise1.sh"
end
```

and in `setup.precise1.sh`:

```
cd /etc/ssh
tar xvf /vagrant/tarfile.tar
```

But you should not do this.

If a client wants to ignore 'known_hosts`, it should ignore that:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no your_vagrant_host
```

or put

```
Host your_vagrant_host
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Your alternative solution of ignoring know_hosts is indeed better. Thanks!